# Installing R with Homebrew

Tags: r, homebrew

I'm trying to install R using Homebrew. I ran these commands which are recommended elsewhere on SO:

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install R
```

For `brew tap homebrew/science`, I'm receiving this error:

```
Error: Already tapped!
```

For the second command, I receive this:

```
Error: No available formula for r
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: seems that almost a year later, this is no longer a problem.  The first 2 commands run with no errors.

Comment: As of 2017, `brew install r` will run just fine.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

As of **2017** / **Brew 1.3.2** @ **macOS Sierra** 10.12.6 all you have to do is:

```
$ brew install r
```

You don't even need to tap [homebrew/science](http://brew.sh/homebrew-science/) since **r** is now a part of core formulae for the Homebrew ([homebrew-core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core)).

It will also install all dependencies automatically:

```
==> Installing dependencies for r: gmp, mpfr, libmpc, isl, gcc
```

There are two additional options you might want to know:

```
--with-java
Build with java support
--with-openblas
Build with openblas support
```

Comment: @Andrew Does brew install r with "--with-java" and "--with-openblas" options?

Comment: @chang02_23 No, by default it is not. These options force `brew` to install `r` with dependencies (`java`, `openblast`). Default installation (`brew install r`) doesn't include those packages.

Comment: For people reading this now, I tried `brew install r` on macOs big sur and realized later that it was doing something else when it took too long to complete. What worked for me is: `brew install --cask r`. Ref. https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/r

Answer (score 238):

As of 2017, it's just `brew install r`. See @Andrew's answer below.

As of 2014 (using an Yosemite), the method is the following:

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install Caskroom/cask/xquartz
brew install r
```

The `gcc` package (will be installed automatically as a required dependency) in the `homebrew/science` tap already contains the latest fortran compiler (`gfortran`), and most of all: the whole package is precompiled so it saves you a lot of compilation time.

This answer will also work for El Capitan and Mac OS Sierra.

In case you don't have XCode Command Line Tools (CLT), run from terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: I also needed to install xquarts $ brew install Caskroom/cask/xquartz

Comment: Another intermediate step as of Jun 9, 2016: `brew link fontconfig`

Comment: You could also skip tapping (if you don't need anything else from homebrew/science) and run `brew install homebrew/science/r`

Comment: See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46208239/3924118, as of 2017, brew 1.3.2, using a macOS Sierra.

Comment: I got error: Error: homebrew/science was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.

Comment: simple `brew install r` worked for me on linuxbrew too (except permissions on Cellar I had to change to work with installing R packages later).

Answer (score 30):

I used this [tutorial](http://davidsimpson.me/2013/02/26/installing-r-on-os-x/) to install R on my mac, and it had me install `xquartz` and a fortran complier (`gfortran`) as well.

My suggestion would be to `brew untap homebrew/science` and then `brew tap homebrew/science` and try again, also, make sure you don't have any errors when you run `brew doctor`

Hope this helps

Comment: GNU Fortran is provided as part of GCC now.

Answer (score 23):

```
brew install cask
brew cask install xquartz
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install r
```

This way, everything is packager managed, so there's no need to manually download and install anything.

Answer (score 15):

Working on El Capitan 10.11.1, the steps I followed are

```
brew install cask    
brew tap homebrew/science    
brew install r
```

Answer (score 8):

This is what actually worked for me on OSX Yosemite.

```
brew install cask
brew install Caskroom/cask/xquartz
brew install r
```

Answer (score 8):

If you run

```
xcode-select --install
```

you do you not need to install `gcc` through `brew`, and you will not have to waste time compiling `gcc`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24967219/2668545 for more details.

After that, you can simply do

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install Caskroom/cask/xquartz
brew install r
```

Answer (score 3):

I am working MacOS 10.10. I have updated gcc to version 4.9 to make it work.

```
brew update
brew install gcc
brew reinstall r
```

Answer (score 3):

```
brew install homebrew/science/r
```

works on OS X 10.11.6.

Answer (score 2):

```
If you meant "r" specifically:
It was migrated from homebrew/science to homebrew/core.
```

For `r 3.4.3` Mac `High Sierra`:

```
brew tap homebrew/core
brew install Caskroom/cask/xquartz
brew install r
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also install R from this page:

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/

It works out of the box

Answer (score 1):

homebrew/science was deprecated
So, you should use the following command.

```
brew tap brewsci/science
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [homebrew page](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/r#default), it is installed with the following command:

```
brew install --cask r
```