# Brew install gcc error - Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)

Tags: homebrew

Trying to install gcc with homebrew and getting the error below. Cannot seem to fix it!

Thought it might be a permissions thing but cannot find where to change permissions.

New to this

> ~ user$ brew install --force gcc
>   ==> Downloading 
>   https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-8.2.0/gcc- 
>   8.2.0.tar.xz
>   Already downloaded:'
>
> /Users/user/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/241c8efec83436d0c5a6fe75389062072fef694334fbbb253d612b0ef7e82cf4--gcc-8.2.0.tar.xz
>
> '==> Patching
>   patching file gcc/graphite.h
>   ==> ../configure --build=x86_64-apple- 
>   darwin14.5.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gc
>   ==> make
>   ^C
>   Error: An exception occured within a build 
>   process:
>   Interrupt: 
>   user$ 
>   user$'
>
> /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:207:in close: Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:207:in rescue in 
>   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:182:in '

Comment: After line `==> make` the `^C` output indicates that `Ctrl-C` may have been pressed to interrupt and cancel the install process. Did you press `Ctrl-C`?

Comment: Yes I pressed that because it was taking so long

Comment: Did it run longer than an hour? Because you are installing gcc from its ***source*** code, about an hour or possibly more is common. See this related question and suggestions [brew install gcc too time consuming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966404/brew-install-gcc-too-time-consuming).

Comment: You can check your "Activity Monitor" App to see the progress of the installation, otherwise, if you don't want to wait for the compilation to finish. You might want to consider the ""bottled" (i.e., precompiled) version of the gcc package, which is very fast, if you have the Xcode Command Line Tools installed. " mentioned in the answer in the previous comment.

Comment: The "python" tag seems irrelevant here; I've removed it.