# brew install gcc too time consuming, pt 2

Tags: gcc

I know this question seems the same as this one

[brew install gcc too time consuming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966404/brew-install-gcc-too-time-consuming)

But there are significant differences going on in my case.  I have tried to homebrew install gcc 3 times now.  The first two times I did not keep track of time but it seemed like they each took two hours and gcc did not install.  This time around I know that 80 minutes has gone by and I am looking at the folder where the gcc is supposed to go.  Homebrew built a new folder called 11.2.0.3 in the gcc folder and for the last 80 minutes absolutely nothing has gone into that folder.

I've tried

brew install gcc --without multilib (or whatever the exact syntax was) and it said that that parameter did not exist.

I also tried

brew install gcc --forced-bottle (or something like that but it said that gcc was not bottled or words to that affect.

Absolutely nothing has happened to my terminal in the last 80 minutes.  It reads

patching file gcc/config/darwin-driver.c
==> ../configure --prefix=/usr/local/opt/gcc --libdir=/usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/11 --disab
==> make

And it stays there. Also, I should add that I'm downloading this because I was to use tesseract.  Do I need xcode for that?  As I recall the last time installed xcode it was something like 16 or maybe 32 gigs.  I don't have that kind of room on my computer for such a download.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.  I just downloaded it while I was asleep.  Who knows how long it took.