# How to install R on Mac OS X 10.10.2 using Homebrew?

Tags: r, installation, homebrew

How to install R on Mac OS X 10.10.2 using Homebrew?  If I simply do

```
brew search R
```

or

```
brew install R
```

it does not do the trick as it did in 10.9.

Comment: did you update homebrew after installing yosemite

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing R with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457290/installing-r-with-homebrew)

Comment: You may also need to reinstall xquartz. When you update your mac OS this is often the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run:

`brew tap homebrew/science
brew install r`

since R is maintained in the [homebrew/science tap](https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-science).

Comment: `homebrew/science` is now deprecated. `r` has been moved to `homebrew/homebrew-core`. See the [readme](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/README.md).