# Run R (from pkg) in terminal on OS X

Tags: r, macos

I just installed MacOS version of *R* from the [CRAN web site](http://www.cran.r-project.org). Within the R GUI application, everything works fine. However, I'm unable to run it from terminal. Trying to trigger `R` or `Rscript` in terminal yields a message indicating that neither command exists.

Also I do not see corresponded scripts in `/Applications/R.app/Contents/`.

How can I run *R* from terminal?

PS: I know [brew installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457290/installing-r-with-homebrew) will help. But I want this version of *R* from CRAN web site.

Comment: Run `locate Rscript` and add the directory where `Rscript` is to your `PATH` variable. Or create a symbolic link of all the files in that directory to your `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin` directories.

Comment: I think you should prbly re-install R from C*R*AN. Both `Rscript` and `R` shld be available from the Terminal if they were installed properly.

Comment: @Abdou thanks, the idea is correct. I've already found the correct file by find / -name R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *R* installer creates `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/` directory in addition to `/Applications/R.app/`.

So, you need add a correct directory to the `Library` dir. For my packages:

```
R_APP_DIR=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/
export PATH=$R_APP_DIR:$PATH
```